# Personal item size

Tags: air-travel, hand-luggage

When an airline defines the maximum sizes of an item like e.g "x=30 cm, y=40 cm, z=10 cm" are the x and y axis sizes exchangeable? for instance could I bring an item whose dimensions are x=40 cm, y=30 cm, z=10 cm?

Comment: There is no difference between an item which is 30x40x10 and one which is 40x30x10. They are the same item just described differently. It's like asking "If the airline defines the maximum weight as 20kg, then can I bring an item which is 44.0925 lbs?"

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes.  All they're asking is that one side is no greater than 40, another 30, and another 10.  They're not asking for it to be facing a particular direction.

Picture a shoe box.  X (width - facing you) of 33cm, 19cm (Y) depth, and 10cm (Z - height).

Now walk around it to view from the side.  Now the width is 19cm (X) facing you, the depth is 33cm, and the height Z is still 10cm.  It still meets their requirements and for the airlines with an example holder, like below, it'll still fit if you turn it around.

[image]